# Exclusive contracting between two classes or interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a method or property that only specified classes can interact with or see.

For example:

```
class Thing
{
    protected int i;
    public virtual int I
    {
        get
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
class OtherThing
{
    public virtual void ChangeI(Thing thing, int i)
    {
        thing.i = i;
    }
}
```

Here, I want ***OtherThing*** to be able to access ***i***, or a protected ***set*** method for ***I*** in ***Thing***, despite being defined outside the scope of ***Thing***.

I recognize that I could simply declare ***OtherThing*** inside the scope of ***Thing***, which would then have permission to access protected items, however I would also like this to work with interfaces, whose implementations cannot be defined within the scope of the original interface, and who can't declare protected methods anyway.

This may not strictly be possible, but I'd love to hear of similar ways to achieve the same thing, just so I can do some experimentation on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course this does not answer the question but first thought that comes to my mind - why do you want to break encapsulation of `Thing`?

Comment: That `virtual int I { get; }` hints that a subclass might implement the property without using the `i` field. Then OtherThing might set it to anything, it will not affect the property value.

Comment: The hypothetical I outlined is just there as a guide - I'm looking for a specific type of behavior, and if it doesn't exist then I'll try and work around it. For the sake of simplicity, and because it generally doesn't, let's assume the 'why' doesn't matter.

Comment: @wigy I'm aware of that - it's entirely hypothetical and irrelevant.

Comment: As all implementation patterns have their proper application area, I definitely think the 'why' does matter. You need to rethink what you are doing if you found a missing language feature in such a widely used language like C# and no relevant answers exist yet on StackOverflow.

Comment: If OtherThing is a factory, Thing might implement an interface explicitly for it. But you cannot restrict classes other than OtherThing to use that interface if they can name the interface.

Comment: @wigy I didn't 'find a missing language feature', I'm inquiring if such a feature exists at all. The hypothetical is there because it's all that's relevant to the question - so often I see people ask "why" someone is looking for a given answer, and it never helps them to answer it. The only thing it does is invite peoples often irrelevant alternatives that OP has likely already explored. You're also omitting the fact that often people simply don't know what to search for, or what keywords to use. The answer may exist already, but it'd be arrogant to assume OP would necessarily find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read the question it feels pretty much like a Visitor pattern:
http://www.dofactory.com/net/visitor-design-pattern

Let's say that you have a visitor:

```
class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var thing = new Thing();
           var otherThing = new OtherThing();
           thing.Accept(otherThing);
           Console.WriteLine(thing.I);
           Console.Read();
       }
   }

   class OtherThing
   {
       public void Change(Action<int> setI)
       {
           setI(42);
       }
   }

   class Thing
   {
       private int i;

       public int I { get { return i; } }

       public void Accept(OtherThing visitor)
       {
           visitor.Change(SetI);
       }

       private void SetI(int i)
       {
           this.i = i;
       }
   }
```

So the idea is: when you accept the visitor you give it a delegate which can change your private field.

I don't really understand the reason, so my example is very artificial. Anyway you can add interfaces to abstract the things, even use some kind of command to pass instead of an Action. But the idea will stay the same.

Comment: I like the idea of using a delegate to expose the setter instead of an interface.

Comment: This looks like a fantastic way of dealing with the problem, thankyou so much! Thanks for trying to work with the hypothetical - as it is now; I can take the general answer you've given me and work with it and understand it. I think that's a much better outcome than wading through lots of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the *friend-class* concept from C++ in C#. C# does not have such a feature on a class-level, so you need to find another design alternative.

Comment: I'd never heard of the 'friend' keyword in c++ until now - thanks. It's a shame that there's no analogue in c#.